# Export a doc or rtf file to a Chrome extension (React+Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, rtf, doc

I'm coding a Chrome extension with React and Typescript. I would like the user to be able to download an editable text file (.doc or .rtf), corresponding to some html code.
How can I do this?

I've tried with the html-to-docx library, but it doesn't seem to work in the case of a Chrome extension.  I've also tried htmlToRtf without success, but maybe that's because I couldn't implement it.